# Suspend auto-shutdown to watch uninturupted video on Firefox

Tags: firefox, 16.04, shutdown

When I'm watching streaming on my Firefox, the computer shuts down automatically, it seems there's no "stay alive" feature.

I'd like to suspend the auto-shutdown for a specific duration : is there a terminal command for that ? (I'd like to avoid messing w/ energy setings)

Answer (score 0):

There's a handy little program called Caffeine for this purpose.

Run these commands in terminal:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:caffeine-developers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install caffeine
```

Now that it's installed, start typing "caffeine preferences" in the dash. Open it when it pops up.

Finally, add Firefox to the list of processes.